# how to show all people with maximun salary MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Need to show all people with max salary, i did but only shows one of them. So i was thinking to use a $max inside of $match, but i cant. i only can use 1 method.

```
db.trabajadores.aggregate([
   {$sort: {salario: -1}},
   {$group:
       { 
        _id: "Trabajador",
        nombre: {$first:"$nombre.nomb"},
        apellido1: {$first:"$nombre.ape1"},
        apellido2: {$first:"$nombre.ape2"}
    }
  }
])
```

this method doesnt work with max inside of match

```
db.trabajadores.aggregate([
{$sort: {salario: -1}},
{$match: {salario: {$max: "$salario"}}},
{$group:
    { 
        _id: "Trabajador",
        nombre: {$first:"$nombre.nomb"},
        apellido1: {$first:"$nombre.ape1"},
        apellido2: {$first:"$nombre.ape2"}
    }
}
])
```

example:

```
db.trabajadores.insert({nombre: {nomb:"Alicia",ape1:"Ramos", ape2:"Martín"},
                    direccion: {población: "Madrid", calle : "Avda Toledo 10"},
                    salario: 1200,
                    oficios:["Profesora", "Analista"],
                    primas: [20,30,40],
                    edad:50
                    })
                    
db.trabajadores.insert({nombre: {nomb:"Juan",ape1:"Gil", ape2:"Sánchez"},
                    direccion: {población: "Madrid", calle : "Mayor 12"},
                    salario: 1400,
                    oficios:["Programador", "Analista"],
                    primas: [120,130,40],
                    edad: 30
                    })

db.trabajadores.insert({nombre: {nomb:"Raquel",ape1:"García", ape2:"del Amo"},
                    direccion: {población: "Toledo", calle : "Ocaña 22"},
                    salario: 1500,
                    oficios:["Profesor"],
                    primas: [60, 30, 80],
                    edad: 45
                    })
db.trabajadores.insert({nombre: {nomb:"Fernando",ape1:"Romo", ape2:"Pérez"},
                    direccion: {población: "Talavera", calle : "Las cañas 2"},
                    salario: 1300,
                    oficios:["Profesor", "Representante"],
                    edad: 43
                    })
db.trabajadores.insert({nombre: {nomb:"María",ape1:"Suárez", ape2:"Verdes"},
                    direccion: {población: "Toledo", calle : "Av Madrid 32"},
                    salario: 1600,
                    oficios:["Profesor", "Contable"],
                    primas: [30, 70, 80],
                    edad: 55
                    })  

 db.trabajadores.insert({nombre: {nomb:"Santiago",ape1:"Gómez", ape2:"Corregidor"},
                    direccion: {población: "Toledo", calle : "Av Madrid 32"},
                    salario: 1600,
                    edad: 55
                    })
```

so i need to show something like this:

```
nombre: Santiago
nombre: Maria
```

because that 2 its the only have max salary.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to do something like this:

```
db.trabajadores.aggregate([
   
   { $group:
       { 
        _id: '$nombre',
        'topSalario': { $sum: '$salario' }
       }
   },
   { $sort: { 'topSalario': -1 } },
   { $limit: 2 }
])
```

Comment: no sorry, i use it and show me all of them

Comment: You can add `{ $limit: 2 }` and you will get the two positions with the highest salary in an ordered list.

Comment: true, but only on this case, what happen if i have more than 2? i just want to show all with max salary(salario), if i have 2 or 3 with max salary, show those 2 or 3.

Comment: So, in a way you have to define the max salary. This is one idea to do it. If you would like to see the highest 10 positions, you can define it with $limit.

Comment: Well, thank you for everything! i will see if i do something, if not, ill show only one and that's it